# How to avoid inline functions in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I follow a React/Redux tutorial and from what I saw on a few articles on internet I realized that inline functions are bad for performance in React.

From what I understood functions are reference type and if you use an inline function, for every re-render, this function will take a different spot in memory.

In the tutorial example I have this deleteExperience() method, that the instructor used inline.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { deleteExperience } from '../../actions/profileActions';

const Experience = ({ experience, deleteExperience }) => {
  const experiences = experience.map(exp => (
    <tr key={exp._id}>
      <td>{exp.company}</td>
      <td className="hide-sm">{exp.title}</td>
      <td>
        <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{exp.from}</Moment> -
        {exp.to === null ? (
          ' Now '
        ) : (
          <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{exp.to}</Moment>
        )}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteExperience(exp._id)}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2 className="my-2">Experience Credentials</h2>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th className="hide-sm">Title</th>
            <th className="hide-sm">Years</th>
            <th />
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{experiences}</tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Experience.propTypes = {
  experience: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  deleteExperience: PropTypes.func
};


export default connect(
  null,
  {deleteExperience}
)(withRouter(Experience));
```

So the instructor said that he used inline function

```
 onClick={() => deleteExperience(exp._id)}
```

and not just called directly the function

```
 onClick={deleteExperience(exp._id)}
```

to not be execute immediately.

So, please someone tell me, if the theory about bad practice to use inline function is true, how to handle this situation? I tried many ways, without any success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance issue isn't from using arrow functions, but rather from creating fresh ones on every render. In your case, you can use [`useCallback()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to memoize them. (You'll need to extract a component to render each `exp` object to avoid breaking [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).) Something like this should work:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { deleteExperience } from '../../actions/profileActions';

const Exp = ({ exp, deleteExperience }) => {
  const del = useCallback(() => deleteExperience(exp._id), [deleteExperience, exp._id]);
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{exp.company}</td>
      <td className="hide-sm">{exp.title}</td>
      <td>
        <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{exp.from}</Moment> -
        {exp.to === null ? (
          ' Now '
        ) : (
          <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{exp.to}</Moment>
        )}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={del}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

const Experience = ({ experience, deleteExperience }) => {
  const experiences = experience.map(exp => (
    <Exp key={exp._id} exp={exp} deleteExperience={deleteExperience} />
  ));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2 className="my-2">Experience Credentials</h2>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th className="hide-sm">Title</th>
            <th className="hide-sm">Years</th>
            <th />
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{experiences}</tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Experience.propTypes = {
  experience: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  deleteExperience: PropTypes.func
};


export default connect(
  null,
  {deleteExperience}
)(withRouter(Experience));
```

Comment: My action deleteExperince, you don't use it anywhere, so when I click on delete nothing happens :).

Comment: @dragon I use it here: `const del = useCallback(() => deleteExperience(exp._id), [exp._id]);`

Comment: @dragon Wait a minute. You have two things both named `deleteExperience`, one that you import and another that's a prop? Answer edited to use the other one.