# Avoid Inline Function Definition in the Render Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw many article said that define inline function in render function in react can cause to performance issue. 
Therefore they recommend to define the function outside of the render function and use it where i need (`onClick` etc).
I built a sample code that i have a list of button and each button will increase the state by the index in the list, But its throw error.
How i can pass parameter and not use inline function in `onClick`

```
const App = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const increaseNumber = (num) => {
    setNumber((prevState) => prevState + num);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {[...Array(5)].map((item, index) => (
        <button key={index} onClick={increaseNumber(index)}>
          {`increase by ${index}`}
        </button>
      ))}
      <div>{number}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Can you share some of those articles you read?

Comment: *"How i can pass parameter and not use inline function in `onClick`"* You can't. Because the function depends on the `.map` callback variable and is therefore different for every element of the array, the function has to be created (directly or indirectly) in the `.map` callback.

Comment: @Spankied This is one of the articles
https://www.codementor.io/blog/react-optimization-5wiwjnf9hj#:~:text=7.-,Avoid,-Inline%20Function%20Definition

Comment: the function is generated on every render. I think u should use `useCallback` to define it only on mount. EDIT: for this function is microptimization, but if you looping to an array with 1000 entities it could cost some time

Comment: Did you try the code suggested in the article?

Comment: @Spankied First thing he use class components so its different. Second thing i didnt understand how he pass `commentId` to `onCommentClick ` function.

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572867/how-to-avoid-inline-functions-in-react-redux

Answer (score 2):

I'll preface my answer by saying you really should profile your application and identify specific performance issues before trying to optimize anything. In this case, you could avoid creating a new callback with each map iteration by using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```
function App() {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);

    const increaseNumber = (event) => {
        const index = parseInt(event.target.dataset.index);
        setNumber((prevState) => prevState + index);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {[...Array(5)].map((item, index) => (
                <button key={index} onClick={increaseNumber} data-index={index}>
                    {`increase by ${index}`}
                </button>
            ))}
            <div>{number}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Typically the only time you would care about creating a new callback per render is when the callback is used as a prop in a child component. Using something like [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) can help to avoid unnecessary child renders in those cases.

Comment: Still defining onclick fn in the render function, but this does answer the question

Comment: @spankied I think you cannot really avoid the inline onClick definition unless you want to query the DOM and then add event listeners manually—that is an even worse option. I think the gist is to not define a new function in onClick (ie an arrow function) but simply pass a memorized function reference or an unchanging function reference (this question offered the latter) is sufficient for a performance gain.

Comment: @spankied There is no need to move the function outside the component definition. Yes it does have a slight performance gain but you harp on the fact that is created in a render function. It is not. The component _returns_ the render function.

Comment: Nice way, but what to do if i need to pass an object to function?
Split the object ?

Comment: @Terry Theres also the issue with setState not being defined outside the component. But ya your response somewhat makes sense. But since JSX compiles to `React.createElement()` does that mean this is `createElement()` is a render fn.

Comment: That's a clever trick, but I am not sure it could be described as a good practice, storing data in the DOM is not the React way.

Comment: @matan I'd recommend encoding an ID or index as a data attribute and use it to look up the correct object from a map or object you store in your app state.

Comment: @tokland Could you explain more about why this specific use of data attributes isn't a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

### Aproach 1: useMemo

When the arguments are fixed like it's your case, you may use `useMemo`:

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const indexes = [...Array(5)].map((_item, idx) => idx);

const App = () => {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);

    const increaseNumber = useMemo(() => {
        return indexes.map(index => () => setNumber(prevNumber => prevNumber + index));
    }, [indexes]);

    return (
        <div>
            {indexes.map(index => (
                <button key={index} onClick={increaseNumber[index]}>
                    increase by {index}
                </button>
            ))}

            <div>{number}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

### Approach 2: wraper component + useCallback

Create your own button component and pass the index:

```
const IncreaseButton = ({ setNumber, index }) => {
    const increaseByIndex = useCallback(() => {
        return setNumber(prevValue => prevValue + index);
    }, [setNumber, index]);

    return <button onClick={increaseByIndex}>increase by {index}</button>;
};
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `index` be passed to the dependency array for `useMemo`?

Comment: @Terry No, `index` is used within the block. `indexes`, on the other hand, *could* be passed. However, as it's defined in the root level, linters would say just to remove it. It could be added for clarity, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an item as a function that had been memoized to the `onClick` prop of `react` button elements.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const increaseNumber = (num) => () => {
    setNumber((prevState) => prevState + num);
  };

  const btns = useMemo(() => {
    // here I am using lodash memoize function you may use your own
    let inc = _.memoize(increaseNumber)
    return Array(500).fill(0).map((_, index) => inc(index))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {btns.map((item, index) => (
        <button key={index} onClick={item}>
          {`increase by ${index}`}
        </button>
      ))}
      <div>{number}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The question is: *"How i can pass parameter and not use inline function in `onClick`"*

Comment: `IncreaseNumber` is still defined inside the render fn. Also adding an anonymous function on the onClick handler might not make much difference.

Comment: This causes an error

Comment: updated, I tested it by more than 500 buttons without any performance issue.